# InDesign: how can I fix pagination so linked text threads are in order again?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm fairly new to InDesign for complex documents (in a past life I used it for magazine layout, but I'm now typesetting a 300 page book using it) and have probably made a rookie error.

My main body text Master Page uses a Primary Text Frame which was linked across the spread. I pasted 90,000 words into it and it automatically reflowed as expected, adding all the pages I needed. So far, so good.

I then did some rearranging, moving pages around (the text is a collection of interviews, which I wanted in a different order). This too seemed fine. I also inserted page breaks at the end of each interview so there was a clean break between each item.

One page has gone a little weird: the page break came at the very end of a page, meaning the following page is now blank. If I delete that blank page, the page which takes its place isn't the next one in the pagination, but the next one that was *originally* there before I re-ordered pages. The same thing happens if I use the arrow keys and try to navigate down onto the blank page: I jump from p149 to p63, not p150.

This effectively means I have a blank page I can't delete. Is there any hope for me here, or will I have to manually re-set all the text? Rearranging the pages wasn't the quickest job in the world and I'd sooner not do it again.

If there's a better way to group each individual item and move them around without manually dragging pages around the spread, though, I'm all ears...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found out: the "story" (the body of the text) is linear, but the placement of the "boxes" (windows looking in on the story) has no such requirement.

If you are re-arranging text in such a way that page 163 flows to page 63, then you have a basic structure problem with the story itself. You should break the story into logical subunits which can be moved/placed independently.

The exact breakdown is up to you--and there is no reason beyond plain craziness why you shouldn't break it down even to sentence level--but you mention interviews plural. At the least each interview should be an atomic unit.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make sense – sounds like I need to break down my monolithic story (which is the entire content in the original order, not the edited order) into separate stories for each content item (interviews).

Comment: in the future, with linked boxes, make a new set of pages and move the boxes, then delete the old pages. Additionally, when doing major reorganization like this, BACK UP your file and give the backup a meaningful name so if it gets tangled up so much you can't make sense of it, you can revert.